# Undefined references with graphics.h in Dev C++?

Tags: c, bgi

I am trying to use `graphics.h` header file and to write a simple program to test whether it works. This is the program which I wrote

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main( )
{
    initwindow(400, 300, "First Sample");
    circle(100, 50, 40);
    while (!kbhit( ))
    {
        delay(200);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile and run this program I get an error as follows,

```
(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `initwindow'
(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `circle'
(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `delay'
```

What can I do to solve this? Please help.

Comment: Add  `-lbgi -lgdi32 -luser32` to linker options

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that on Dev C++.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/33274/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `graphics.h` in linux, then this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu) will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project then go to your project options, go to compiler and select 32-bit release, it will work.